# GridView tutorial: insufficient storage issue

Tags: android

I'm was trying with GridView tutorial with 14 of my own JPEGs.
The first time I ran it worked but had an issue when I clicked on an image.
I figured it might be because I left and extra comma at the end of my mThumbIds list.

But when I tried to run again I get:
[2010-09-07 15:59:36 - HelloGridView] Installing HelloGridView.apk...
[2010-09-07 15:59:44 - HelloGridView] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE
[2010-09-07 15:59:44 - HelloGridView] Please check logcat output for more details.

These files do not take up much space (~20Mb). I restarted the AVD but keep getting the same issue. (Not sure what "logcat" refers to but Error Log had nothing.)

Can anyone tell me what is going on and how to fix this?

Comment: LogCat is where stack traces from exceptions appear, among other messages. You can view it via `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

What device is it? I know 20MB is would probably max me out on my Nexus One. Have you tried manually uninstalling the application from your phone before uploading it again? All I can think of is maybe if some pictures were renamed or replaced the old ones might still be sitting on your phone hogging space. Can you view these pictures in the file explorer in the DDMS perspective in Eclipse?

Comment: Thanks. I'm just using the AVD. DDMS view (logcat) didn't have much more info. and I don't know my way around the DDMS file system yet to view the picture data. But I manually altered all my pictures sizes down to 400x300pix and now the app. works! There should be some guide as to how much resource size you can upload.

Comment: I'm sorry I didnt notice you said AVD. You can uninstall your apps there like you would on your phone, through the home->menu->settings->applications options which may vary depending on the version of android being emulated.

When you first start the emulator there is also a checkbox to clear user data.